# Why in the BCS ground state the probability amplitudes are taken real?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity, many-body

In some references (see for example Ballentine ch. 18.5) the ground state of the BCS theory is assumed to be

\begin{equation}
|BCS\rangle = \prod_{\bf k} (u_{\bf k}+v_{\bf k}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{\bf k,\uparrow}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{-\bf k,\downarrow})|0\rangle.
\end{equation}

with the normalization constraint $u_{\bf k}^2 + v_{\bf k}^2 = 1$.

The same can be found in the original paper by Bardeen, Cooper and Schrieffer where you can read

\begin{equation}
|BCS\rangle = \prod_{\bf k}( (1-h_{\bf{k}})^{1/2} + h_{\bf{k}}^{1/2} b^{\dagger}_k |0\rangle.
\end{equation}

But in other books like the one by Annett those parameters are considered complex.

Why the parameter $u_{\bf k}$ and $v_{\bf k}$ are taken real? 
Shouldn't they be taken complex amplitudes? Is this state a classical mixture?

My guess is that this choice is justified a posteriori, but I cannot find any detail about it in any reference I have read.

Comment: This is clearly explained here http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bardeen-Cooper-Schrieffer_theory

Comment: The article says that "The phase of the ground state may be chosen so that with no loss of generality $u_k$ is real." Obviously, with a change of basis, you can always take one of the two parameters as real, but you still will have the other parameter $v_k$ complex in general.
In fact just below is stated:
$u=\sqrt{1-h}; v=\sqrt{h}\exp(i\phi)$

Comment: Yes, the most general case includes a phase, so u,v are treated as components of a complex number with magnitude 1. Is your question on the physical meaning of a nonzero phase is? If so, you may want to edit your question

Comment: My doubt is why I am allowed to ignore the phase, how can I be sure to come to the correct result?  So, as I said in my question, why the parameters can be taken real?

Comment: If you read carefully the link you will see they do not ignore the phase, they simply minimize the free energy with respect to it and find it should be taken to be zero for their Hamiltonian. From there, all the usual BCS behaviors are derived.

Comment: Thanks for having pointed out this derivation. However this not solve my question. I am convinced that derivation you have linked is correct. But then why the authors of BCS paper are allowed to take both the parameters real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question on page 86 of the following document
https://www.physik.tu-dresden.de/~timm/personal/teaching/thsup_w11/Theory_of_Superconductivity.pdf

Here is clear that we have no reason a priori to assume that the two parameters are real. Therefore we should start with complex amplitudes.

Searching for the energy of the states we get to

\begin{equation}
\langle BCS|\hat{H} | BCS \rangle = \sum_{\bf{k}} 2 \xi_k |v_{\bf{k}}|^2+\sum_{\bf{k}} V_{\bf{kk'}} v_{\bf{k}}u^*_{\bf{k}}u_{\bf{k'}}v^*_{\bf{k'}}
\end{equation}

From this expression is clear that, in order to avoid a complex energy, $v_{\bf{k}}$ and $u_{\bf{k}}$ should have the same phase.
Therefore, without loss of generality, we can take both parameters as real numbers.